# Cannot set $form-feedback-invalid-color with Bootstrap 4.5.0

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I have the following global `scss`:

```css
/* Importing Bootstrap SCSS file. */

@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';

...

$danger: darken($red, 15%);

$theme-colors: (
  "danger": $danger
);

...

$form-feedback-invalid-color: $danger;

...
```

I have the following `<form>`

```html
<form
  ngNoForm
  name="loginForm"
  action="/account/login"
  method="post"
  novalidate
>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Email Address:</label>
    <input
      type="email"
      class="form-control form-control-sm"
      [class.is-invalid]="email.invalid && email.dirty"
      id="username"
      name="username"
      [(ngModel)]="username"
      tabindex="1"
      email
      required
      placeholder="Email Address"
      #usernameInput
      #email="ngModel"
    />
    <small class="help-block text-danger" *ngIf="email.invalid && email.dirty">
      A valid email address is required.
    </small>
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

which renders as follows:

[image: login-form]

Originally, `$danger` is `$red` which is `#dc3545`. As you can see, the input for username takes the border color of `#dc3545` when it is invalid:

[image: css-input]

However the text with `text-danger` class is in the correct color of `#a71d2a`.

[image: css-text]

What am I doing wring when setting up the color for border of an invalid input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that:

Bootstrap's `_variables.scss` is this:

```
// Form validation

...

$form-feedback-invalid-color:       theme-color("danger") !default;
$form-feedback-icon-invalid:        url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='12' height='12' fill='none' stroke='#{$form-feedback-icon-invalid-color}' viewBox='0 0 12 12'><circle cx='6' cy='6' r='4.5'/><path stroke-linejoin='round' d='M5.8 3.6h.4L6 6.5z'/><circle cx='6' cy='8.2' r='.6' fill='#{$form-feedback-icon-invalid-color}' stroke='none'/></svg>") !default;

...

$form-validation-states: () !default;
$form-validation-states: map-merge(
  (

    ...

    "invalid": (
      "color": $form-feedback-invalid-color,
      "icon": $form-feedback-icon-invalid
    ),
  ),
  $form-validation-states
);
```

So to override `$form-feedback-invalid-color`, I also needed to override `$form-validation-states` because that's where Bootstrap reads it. [Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#customizing).